# Does "knee-jerk" mean having a lot of leeway here?

Tags: meaning

https://www.npr.org/2023/11/13/1212767277/maryanne-trump-barry-dead says

> Years before her brother became president, Barry wrote in a 2006
> immigration case that judges had too little leeway to evaluate who
> should get to remain in the U.S. because of rigid laws that force
> "knee-jerk" decisions.

If laws are rigid and don't give judges much leeway, why does that lead to forcing knee-jerk decisions?

knee-jerk means  automatic and unthinking. Doesn't that mean not being limited by laws, and therefore having a lot of leeway?

Thanks.

Comment: A knee-jerk situation allows little or (usually) no leeway whatsoever. If your knee jerks by reflex, you did not choose whether, when, or how strongly your knee jerked. The term comes from the classic reflex demonstration where a person's knee is struck with an instrument resembling a rubber hammer. The response is outside the person's control.

Comment: In context, it's an "unusual" (awkward, inappropriate) metaphoric usage. Knee-jerk reactions are caused by being ***taken unawares / surprised*** and/or being *[contemptuously] **unwilling to give due consideration** [to an issue]*. Those are hardly credible reasons for why judges don't exercise much leeway when ruling on immigration cases, so to call their decisions "knee-jerk reactions" doesn't make a lot of sense to me. They're perfectly familiar with such cases, since they often hear them, and *it's their job* to give them due consideration. They just have little leeway, is all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Exactly. It's pejorative. A knee-jerk reaction is one which ought not to have happened; the implication being that the appropriate amount of thought or consideration was not done.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I don't understand what you're telling me. Do you think the cited usage ***is*** "natural", or are you agreeing with me that it's stylistically weak phrasing? How does the fact of laws being relatively inflexible make judges naturally careless of their duties?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - sorry for being unclear. I'm agreeing with you one hundred percent that it's stylistically weak and opinionated phrasing. The phrase appears to be a direct quote from a speech by Maryanne Trump Barry, a retired US federal judge and former President Donald Trump 's oldest sister, (the AP story is about the fact that she has died at age 86). This lady is quoted as reported as saying that her brother, the (hopefully always) former president 'has no principles' and was 'cruel'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers She used 'knee-jerk decision' about a case where US law prevented asylum being granted to a former Irish National Liberation Army member who had a UK criminal conviction for wounding a police officer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: oic. Yes, you're quite right that "knee-jerk reaction" is (as usual) *intended* to be pejorative. But the reason it's clumsy is because Barry doesn't seem to know whether she's taking a poke at (lazy) ***judges*** or (inflexible) ***laws***. And of course, judges don't *make* the laws (that's what politicians and presidents do), so it kinda matters where she's pinning the blame.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in 'common law' legal systems, like those of the UK and USA, judges do make laws, in the sense that they interpret legislation. This is different from the situation in countries which have 'codified' legislation. I begin to see what Ms Barry was getting at. Lazy or pusillanimous judges?

Comment: At the July 9 announcement of his nomination to the US Supreme Court, Judge Brett Kavanaugh said that judges should interpret the law, not make the law. [...] It is time to stop saying this nonsense. If the law were that easy to interpret and apply, the Supreme Court would have no cases to decide. [...] Supreme Court justices do make law; it is the reasons for their decisions that matter. What democracy requires are justices who are non-partisan, independent, and fair. - Wendy Mariner, Edward  R. Utley Professor of Health Law, Ethics & Human Rights at Boston School of Public Health.

Comment: Worth noting that US judges are generally elected, or in the case of the Supreme Court, appointed by the sitting president, and confirmed by the Senate, so you would think it might be hard to avoid some political bias. This is unlike the UK.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *knee-jerk* means automatic and unthinking - so judges had to apply the law rigidly. "A gets to stay because he fulfils the right conditions; B cannot stay because she doesn't."

Mrs Barry suggested that judges should have more leeway to say "Even though B doesn't fulfil all the conditions, I have decided to permit her to stay because [of mitigating circumstances]".